# Property y does not exist on type x when prop deconstruction

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've created a simple `projectname.tsx` file in which I want to house my interfaces/types:

```
export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  posterPath: string;
}
```

In a different component I want to use the Movie interface to define a prop as of interface Movie:

```
const MovieOnDashboard = ({movie}: Movie) => {
  const imagePath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/';
  return (
    <MovieContainer
      key={movie.id}>
      <img src={imagePath + movie.posterPath} alt='poster' />
    </MovieContainer>
  );
};
```

The prop `{movie}` shows a error:

> Property 'movie' does not exist on type 'Movie'.

I use prop deconstruction `{movie}` because the prop has been passed down, meaning the actual prop is `movie.movie`. The error makes sense because property `movie` is not defined in the movie interface.

I don't want to define a movie object on my movie interface, so how do I enforce that the deconstructed prop is of type movie?

Comment: You probably need to write `{movie}: { movie: Movie }` if the movie is passed as a prop

Comment: Holy syntaxin Batman. What does this code do? Deconstruct the prop into a movie object. Then it assigns the deconstructed movie object to interface Movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir mentioned use

`{movie}: { movie: Movie }`

which is literally like

`prop: { movie: Movie }` but you Deconstruct the prop and only get the property`movie`